# Pandas datetime convert & filter issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas 0.8.1 to fetch Yahoo stock price

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

stk_price = DataReader('600809.ss', 'yahoo', datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2012,12,31)).reset_index()

>>> stk_price.Date
0    2010-01-04 00:00:00
1    2010-01-05 00:00:00
2    2010-01-06 00:00:00
3    2010-01-07 00:00:00
4    2010-01-08 00:00:00
```

And I want to convert the Date to string by:

```
>>>stk_price.Date.astype('|S10')
0     1970-01-15
1     1970-01-15
2     1970-01-15
3     1970-01-15
4     1970-01-15
5     1970-01-15
```

Why it shows "1970-01-15" instead of "2010-01-04" etc ? How to fix it?

And if I have a

```
DATE_LIST = [
 u'20090331', u'20090630', u'20090930', u'20091231', \
 u'20100331', u'20100630', u'20100930', u'20101231', \
 u'20110331', u'20110630', u'20110930', u'20111231', \
 u'20120331', u'20120630', u'20120930', u'20121231'
 ]
```

I just try to filter the rows of `stk_price` whose Date column is in `DATE_LIST` by below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import numpy as np

DATE_LIST = [
 u'20090331', u'20090630', u'20090930', u'20091231', \
 u'20100331', u'20100630', u'20100930', u'20101231', \
 u'20110331', u'20110630', u'20110930', u'20111231', \
 u'20120331', u'20120630', u'20120930', u'20121231'
 ]

DATE_ARRAY = np.array(DATE_LIST,dtype='datetime64[us]')
stk_price = DataReader('600809.ss', 'yahoo', datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2012,12,31)).reset_index()
rst = stk_price[stk_price.Date.isin(DATE_ARRAY)].Close
```

but the rst is empty .

How to fix it or any Pandas function can filter the result ?

Comment: if you have two different questions don't combine them into one. The second question is hard to understand - i suggest you rephrase it, split it up and ask it again. Answered the first one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting stk_price dates to strings (which shows the wrong dates due to a numpy bug, see also [github issue #1802](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1802)) you can also convert the DATE_LIST to timestamps and use these directly to index stk_price. Below an example on frame containing random data.

```
In [16]: DATE_LIST = [
 u'20090331', u'20090630', u'20090930', u'20091231', \
 u'20100331', u'20100630', u'20100930', u'20101231', \
 u'20110331', u'20110630', u'20110930', u'20111231', \
 u'20120331', u'20120630', u'20120930', u'20121231'
 ]

In [17]: timestamps = [pd.Timestamp(date) for date in DATE_LIST]

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3), index=pd.date_range('20090331', periods=100))

In [19]: df.ix[timestamps].dropna()
Out[19]:
                   0         1         2
2009-03-31  0.520235  1.158889 -0.310227
2009-06-30  1.036449  0.528931 -0.083166
```

Answer (score 2):

use `df.Date=df.Date.apply(lambda x:x.date())` to convert the datetime column

```
>>> df=DataFrame({'Date':[datetime(2006,1,1)]})
>>> df
                  Date
0  2006-01-01 00:00:00
>>> df.Date=df.Date.apply(lambda x:x.date())
>>> df
         Date
0  2006-01-01
```

EDIT:

to format DATE_LIST

```
dates=[datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y%m%d").date() for i in DATE_LIST]
```

and finally use `isin` to filter out the rows that are in DATE_LIST:

```
df[df['Dates'].isin(dates)]
```

in one go(given that you have stk_price dataframe that has a datecolumn called Date):

```
import datetime

stk_price = DataReader('600809.ss', 'yahoo', datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2012,12,31)).reset_index()
stk_price.Date=stk_price.Date.apply(lambda x:x.date())
dates=[datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y%m%d").date() for i in DATE_LIST]
stk_price[stk_price['Dates'].isin(dates)]
```

Comment: stk_price = DataReader('600809.ss', 'yahoo', datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2012,12,31)).reset_index() ; stk_price['Date'][0] is <Timestamp: 2006-01-02 00:00:00> . Type not match with dates (<type 'datetime.date'>) .  stk_price[stk_price['Date'].isin(dates)] returns empty dataframe.

Comment: yes, >>> dates=[datetime(*time.strptime(i,'%Y%H%M')[:3]).date() for i in DATE_LIST]

Comment: I do not catch your idea. so would you pls directly paste the code to filter out the 'stk_price' against 'DATE_LIST' ? Thanks ...